# Resize view and change layout of controls based on subview

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, ios-autolayout

In my viewcontroller I have created a container view and some other controls.
Based on some conditional logic the appropriate subview (xib) is created and added to the container view in `ViewDidLoad()`

I am trying to work out a how to make the container view change height so it's the same size as the subview and make all the other controls change position (i.e. by moving up/ down) depending on the height.
I am trying to do this by using layout constraints because I'm targetting iPhones and iPads.

I tried adding a height constraint so the height of the container view is the same as the height of the subview but this did not work:

```
MyContainerView.HeightAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(MySubView.HeightAnchor, 1).Active = true;
```

As you can see in the screen shots the container view does not change height.
[image]
[image]

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Just a quick check: Did you call `UIView.SetNeedsLayout` on the container view after activating the constraint?

Comment: Which one  is MyContainerView? MySubView?

Comment: @LarryOBrien oooh no I didn't, will try that.